# Neo4j TransactionNotPresentOnMasterException

Tags: neo4j

I've set up a HA cluster using one standalone instance and one embedded.

When the embedded instance is slave and I have a longer taking transaction (commit time about 30s), it throws:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
  at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:143)
  ... 4 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.com.TransactionNotPresentOnMasterException: Transaction RequestContext[session: 1372752815336, ID:3, eventIdentifier:0, [lucene-index/1311102, nioneodb/7397657]] has either timed out on the master or was not started on this master. There may have been a master switch between the time this transaction started and up to now. This transaction cannot continue since the state from the previous master isn't transferred.
  at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterImpl.suspendOtherAndResumeThis(MasterImpl.java:280)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterImpl.finishTransaction(MasterImpl.java:457)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.HaRequestType18$14.call(HaRequestType18.java:188)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.HaRequestType18$14.call(HaRequestType18.java:183)
  at org.neo4j.com.Server$4.run(Server.java:559)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

As stated in the exception, I've checked wether the standalone instance loses it's master state, but it doesn't. So no master switch occurs. The instances are running on the same machine, so a network error can't be the cause.

When the embedded instance is master or not in any cluster, the transaction succeeds.

The code generating this error is quite complex, so I can't put an example here atm.

Comment: If I can provide sth. useful let me know and I'll add it here.

Comment: I think I have found a solution. I put these options for the embedded instances:

    ha.read_timeout: 60,
    ha.state_switch_timeout: 60,
    ha.slave_only: true